# Laravel 5.1 File not deleting from folder

Tags: laravel-5.1

I want to delete a pdf file form my database as well as my public/uploads folder. It is deleting from the database but not from my public folder.

This is my controller:

```
 public function deleteArticle($id) {
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);

     File::delete($article->document);
        $article->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
   }

   /*This handles the posting of the file into the folder and storing of the url into the datab
   $file = Input::file('document');
   $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
   $document = asset('uploads/'.$file->getClientOriginalName());

   $newArticle->document = $document;
```

Comment: what do you save in $article->document ? Is it like  public/uploads/document1.pdf  or just document1.pdf ?

Comment: `$article->document` contains `http://localhost/blog/public/uploads/name_of_document.pdf`. That is the link in my database

Comment: Unfortunately this is not ideal, as you save a URL and not a file path. You can't delete a file by providing a url to that file.

Comment: i see, so how do i go about it ? I have updated my question to show the code that post the file and save the url into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are currently saving a url to the database ( by using the asset() function ) you can't delete the file by using that information.

It is usually enough to save just the document name in the database.

```
  $document = $file->getClientOriginalName();

  $newArticle->document = $document;
```

To delete the file you can then call:

```
File::delete(public_path('uploads/'.$article->document);
```

To Link to your file you can use the asset() method

```
asset('uploads/'.$article->document);
```

Comment: in my database i see `uploads\name_of_file.pdf`          but when i try deleting, i get this error `LogicException in Model.php line 2673:
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Comment: Its working thank you all for your contribution. I really appreciate your efforts....

Comment: oh I did not really mean, accepting the answer. Just an upvote would have been enough. I don't want to steal the accepted answer from smartrahat

Answer (score 0):

Storing the full URL in database is a bad idea. It will very hard to maintain files later. The best way is store only the filename with extension.

If you only have the filename in database, you can delete the file in this way:

```
$article = Article:findOrFail($id);
$document = $article->document;      // take the image name from database
File::delete('uploads/'.$document);  // delete the file 
$article->delete()                   // delete the record from database
```

**Edit**

If you still want to use URL in database you can get the image name by using `substr()` and `strpos()` function. Example:

```
$image = substr($article->document,0,strpos("uploads/"));
```

You can get only the document name from URL and use it to delete the file.

To store only the filename follow this:

```
$document = $request->file('document')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: Yes i completely understand but how do i store the filename alone because when ever i do this `$file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
    $document = asset('uploads/'.$file->getClientOriginalName());

    $newArticle->document = $document;` It stores the whole url

Comment: see my answer ?